# Can't add dashlets on dashboard

Tags: dashboard

on Drupal 7.67 + CiviCRM 5.32.2 I do can see the dashlets but I lost ability to add and suppress them, so I guess Ajax doesn't work any more. It stopped working with the upgrade to 5.32.2 before it was functioning.

Clicking on the cross also has no impact but I can move them once added on the dashboard.

Changing the jquery version in theme settings doesn't help (I've tried various versions from 1.4 to 3.1).

Is there a special setting in CiviCRM or is it a bug in 5.32.2?

[image]

These are the message in the javascript console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' js_tirzwVKQe_kXpvFPxNVA-vmv7H54qthEMinEoehf1m8.js:12:51
else this._+='L'+(this._x1=t)+','+(this._y1=n);else},arc:function(t,n,e,r,i,a){t=+t,n=+n;var l=(e=+e)*Math.cos(r),f=e*Math.sin(r),u=t+l,c=n+f,s=1^a,o=a?r-i:i-r;if(e<0)throw new Error('negative radius: '+e);null===this._x1?this._+='M'+u+','+c:(Math.abs(this._x1-u)>1e-6||Math.abs(this._y1-c)>1e-6)&&(this._+='L'+u+','+c),e&&(o<0&&(o=o%Ua+Ua),o>Dp?this._+='A'+e+','+e+',0,1,'+s+','+(t-l)+','+(n-f)+'A'+e+','+e+',0,1,'+s+','+(this._x1=u)+','+(this._y1=c):o>1e-6&&(this._+='A'+e+','+e+',0,'+ +(o>=Fa)+','+s+','+(this._x1=t+e*Math.cos(i))+','+(this._y1=n+e*Math.sin(i))))},rect:function(t,n,e,r){this._+='M'+(this._x0=this._x1=+t)+','+(this._y0=this._y1=+n)+'h'+ +e+'v'+ +r+'h'+-e+'Z'},toString:function(){return this._}};function ri(){};function gt(t,n){var r=new ri;if(t instanceof ri)t.each(function(t,n){r.set(n,t)});else if(Array.isArray(t)){var a,e=-1,o=t.length;if(null==n)for(;++e<o;)r.set(e,t[e]);else for(;++e<o;)r.set(n(a=t[e],e,t),a)}
```

Comment: Are there errors in the javascript console?

Comment: I've edited my message with the errors and messages.

Comment: The `Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'` is key, but since the name of the file in question is obfuscated in your paste, I can't read it. Best click on the error in the console and it will take you to the offending line of code. Take a screenshot of that.

Comment: I've edited my post with the error message for Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'

Comment: That js does contain a syntax error. To find out who's responsible for it, try a grep for 'negative radius: ' and see what module/extension contains that code,

Comment: 'negative radius' comes from the civisualize module but disabling it doesn't change the behaviour. The other JS error comes from JQuery. As written, I unsuccessfully tried several JQuery engine so I guess I'll wait for the new version of CiviCRM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely there is a js code error somewhere on your site (could be from any module). Keep debugging it by clicking the error message in the console.

But FYI, CiviCRM v5.33 comes with completely rewritten dashboard code. So upgrading may solve your problem too.

Comment: Great to know! Thanks for this information Coleman

Comment: update to version 5.33 corrected this .js error. Thanks @coleman